# Is there such a thing as "page optimization" in compilers?

Tags: memory-management, compiler-construction, virtual-memory

I'm studying the basics of memory management and haven't found an answer for this.
Do the compilers, somehow, try to optimize the code in such a way that the pages are better read or used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many compilers will attempt to optimise the placement of loops so that the loop instructions are entirely contained within a single cache line, if possible. Similarly, attempts are often made to keep stack frames cache-line aligned.

Since cache lines do not cross virtual page boundaries, such optimisations could also reduce the number of page faults. However, the main purpose is to avoid cache misses.